# Ant get task failed to download from https endpoint

Tags: java, jenkins, ant

I have an Ant task that will download composer from https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar

```
<target name="composer-download" depends="composer-check" unless="composer.present">
    <get src="https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar" dest="${composer}"/>
</target>
```

But I'm hitting the error

[image]

It works fine if I change the url to http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar

Comment: Works fine for me. Try logging in to the same machine that's running this script and run `wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar .`

Comment: I have tried before, no issue using `wget`